# OpenCV GrabCut Remove Background

Tags: python, opencv3.0

I have been able to remove about 75% of the background from my original image, but I am struggling to fine tune my python code to remove the last bit.

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NY3Ne.jpg)

[Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqKir.png)

As you can see there is one section of the background on the lower half of the image that isn't being removed along with the rest.

```
import os, time
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

org_file_name = 'IMG_3237_reduced.jpg'

#Read Image File
img = cv2.imread(org_file_name))

mask = np.zeros(img.shape[:2],np.uint8)
bgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
fgdModel = np.zeros((1,65),np.float64)
rect = (1,1,1008,756)
rect2 = (11,222,975, 517)

# Perform the GrabCut on the Image File
t1 = time.clock()
cv2.grabCut(img,mask,rect2,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv2.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
t2 = time.clock()
print(t2-t1)

mask2 = np.where((mask==2)|(mask==0),0,1).astype('uint8')
gc_img = img*mask2[:,:,np.newaxis]

# convert to grayscale
gc_img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(gc_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_,alpha = cv2.threshold(gc_img_gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
b, g, r = cv2.split(gc_img)
rgba = [b,g,r, alpha]
gc_split_img = cv2.merge(rgba,4)

# display results
#ax1 = plt.subplot(131); plt.imshow(img)
#ax1.set_title('Original')
#ax2 = plt.subplot(132); plt.imshow(gc_img)
#ax2.set_title('GrabCut')
ax3 = plt.subplot(111); plt.imshow(gc_split_img)
ax3.set_title('GrabCut Split')
plt.show()
```

I've attached the my working code above. I appreciate any help someone can offer. My plan is once the background is removed, I can do some analysis/statical  modeling on the region of interest for further comparison.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one time process, I don't think you need to use grabcut. I'd suggest something like this, where you use a combination of spatial and simple code value thresholding:

```
import cv2
import numpy

# Read Image File
img = cv2.imread('NY3Ne.jpg')

# convert RGB to grayscale image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

mask, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

rect_x = [15, 990]
rect_y = [220, 530]

y, x = numpy.indices(img.shape[:2])

# threshold based on otsu's method
img[mask < thresh] = 0
# set everything outside the rectangle to 0
img[(x < rect_x[0])] = 0
img[(x > rect_x[1])] = 0
img[(y < rect_y[0])] = 0
img[(y > rect_y[1])] = 0

cv2.imshow('masked', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But if grabcut is necessary for some other reason, I could combine it with simple thresholding to get the desired result. 150 is kind of arbitrary based on your image, but you could substitute Otsu or any other adaptive binary threshold calculation method.

```
alpha = np.where(gc_img_gray < 150, 255, 0).astype(np.uint8)
gc_img[alpha==0] = 0
```

More info: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/d7/d4d/tutorial_py_thresholding.html